# Как получить с фроненда(js) экселевский файл на бекенде (Spring)?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-mvc

Gосылаю с фронтенда файл

```
const invokeSavePayments = file => fetch("/rest/importPayments", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    enctype: "multipart/form-data",
  },
  body: file,
});
```

На стороне сервера пытаюсь получить файл или InputStream так:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/importPayments"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Map<String, List<Payment>> importPayments(@RequestBody MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
```

В file переменной получаю null. 
Пробовал вариант c @RequestParam - получаю ошибку 
500 Internal Server Error

Current request is not a multipart request

> Stacktrace: org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException:
>   Current request is not a multipart request
>       at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValue(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:190)

Бекенд на спринг, из настроек, добавлен dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

и бин в контекст

```
 <bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>
```

Как получить с фронтенда файл?

Comment: Попробуйте '@RequestPart' вместо '@RequestBody'

Comment: @RomanDanilov то же сообщение об ошибке

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Фронт:

```
var input = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');

var data = new FormData();
data.append('file', input.files[0]);

const invokeSavePayments = file => fetch("/rest/importPayments", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    enctype: "multipart/form-data",
  },
  body: data,
});
```

Бэк:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/importPayments", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Map<String, List<Payment>> importPayments(@RequestParam MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
   ...
}
```